# chromecast framework not recognising cast button

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, button, chromecast, google-cast

I have a HTML 5 player app that has a requirement to load all of its skin elements programmatically.

I am attempting to add a Google Cast button to the skin. To do this I have the following code:

```
var castButton = document.createElement("button");
castButton.setAttribute("is", "google-cast-button");
```

this button is appended to the page and appears within the DOM on inspection. The problem I am having his that the framework des not recognise it as the cast button. So when clicking it no devices are listed.

In the chromecast chrome API docs it states [cast docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate#cast_button) that I can create the button using

```
document.createElement("button", "google-cast-button");
```

I am not able to use the second argument as I'm working in typescript and it has no knowledge of the second argument.

an example of the problem I am having in it's simplest form can be found here

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Cast%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myButton%3A%20HTMLButtonElement%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myButton%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22buton%22)%20as%20HTMLButtonElement%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20google%20documentation%20would%20have%20me%20do%20document.createElement(%22buton%22%2C%20%22google-cast-button%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(this.myButton)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20cast%20%3D%20new%20Cast()%3B%0D%0Acast.myButton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%22cast%20click%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

When '__onGCastApiAvailable' is called by the framework when it has successfully loaded, the button should be set as the cast button but is not.

If I add a simple button to the HTML

```
<button id="cast-start" is="google-cast-button" style="width: 30px;"></button>
```

This works?

Is there something I'm missing or is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Typescripts support for document.createElement(); see the below link for a more in depth discussion and solution[typescript number of arguments error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166657/typescript-number-of-arguments-error)

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [support page](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6279412?hl=en) which provides troubleshooting steps when you can't find the Cast button:

- Make sure the [Chrome browser is up to date](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414).
- The Cast button is in the overflow area.

Also, you may first try [this troubleshooter form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSewdhsx6w69iDDuCCiHW_ZEkVYD50pyYsGDKYeqddnkIPlE3w/viewform) from this [page](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3249268?hl=en) to help solve the most common issues causing missing devices.

Here's a sample [CastButton.js](https://github.com/meisterplayer/ui-standardui/blob/f25d2e67f7f8f5d5c19b890870ee12e093fa6b41/src/js/top/CastButton.js).